# Netezza create table by union 2 tables

Tags: netezza

I am trying to create (CTAS) a table in Netezza using

```sql
Create table A as (select * from B union select * from C)
```

I am getting an error `cross database access not supported` although all the tables reside on the same database.
Any pointers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the query you are using and the complete error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

In netezza, the only kind of ‘cross database access’ that is NOT supported is ‘writing’.
Unlike SQLserver you need to switch you ‘current database’ to the one where table A is going to land before you run the query.